# URL encoding giving errors when contacting API

Tags: javascript, json, url, encoding

I'm working on a school project where I'm trying to make a search function for The New York Times Article Search API.
I have a problem with one of their search filters as when I run the function I get error 400 as for some reason it can't read the url encoding. The fun thing is if I replace all the %3D's with = and the %26's with & in my own URL it works and I can see the API responds correctly.

```
if($('#date1').is(':checked')) {date="day_of_week&begin_date=18500101&end_date=19000101";}
if($('#date2').is(':checked')) {date="day_of_week&begin_date=19000101&end_date=19500101";}
if($('#date3').is(':checked')) {date="day_of_week&begin_date=19500101&end_date=20000101";}
if($('#date4').is(':checked')) {date="day_of_week&begin_date=20000101&end_date=20150101";}

$.getJSON('http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json',
{'api-key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
'fq': 'headline:("'+sogestreng.toLowerCase()+'")'+" AND "+finalSections,
'facet_field': date},
```

This code returns "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?api-key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&fq=headline%3A(%22dubai%22)+AND+section_name.contains%3A(%22Sports%2C+%22)&facet_field=day_of_week%26begin_date%3D20000101%26end_date%3D20150101"

While if I manually replace the last part of the url encoding and open it in my browser I get the result I'm looking for.

I do this by changing:

"&facet_field=day_of_week%26begin_date%3D20000101%26end_date%3D20150101"

to

"&facet_field=day_of_week&begin_date=20000101&end_date=20150101"

Also to clarify, the "fq" criteria works perfectly fine, it's just the facet_field.

How can this be? And is there any fix for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're shoving the description of several fields into one field's value. To get the results you want, try:

```
var begin_date, end_date;

if($('#date1').is(':checked')) {      
  begin_date = 18500101;
  end_date = 19000101;
}
else if($('#date2').is(':checked')) {
  // etc.
}


$.getJSON('http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json',
  {
    'api-key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'fq': 'headline:("'+sogestreng.toLowerCase()+'")'+" AND "+finalSections,
    'facet_field': 'day_of_week',
    'begin_date': begin_date,
    'end_date': end_date
  },
// ...
```

Comment: Worked, thanks! Seems quite a stupid question now that you explained it :)